# Artificial Intelligence Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to work on making a batch script i modified to output to a file the inputs and outputs, read the script and you will understand, but i have been unable to get it to read the file, i can get it to create it and write to it, but reading it is not working. Thanks if anyone can provide any insite. PS, it is supposed to output to a file called IO_DATA, and yes i know it has no file extension, but i do that purposely, and no thats not the issue, it still reads and rights as a text document.

```
@ECHO OFF 
setlocal

COLOR 0a
title I/O System
cls
ECHO ** I/O System Initialized **
ECHO ****************************

if not exist IO_DATA echo ----------------------------------------
if not exist IO_DATA echo IO_DATA FILE NOT FOUND! CREATING NEW...
if not exist IO_DATA echo ----------------------------------------
if not exist IO_DATA echo.>IO_DATA


:begin
ECHO INPUT:
set INPUT=OUTPUT
SET /P INPUT=
set INPUT=%INPUT:?=%
call :%INPUT: =% 2>NUL
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto begin


echo UNDEFINED INPUT "%INPUT%"
ECHO DEFINE


set /P OUTPUT=
echo :%INPUT: =% >> IO_DATA
echo echo OUTPUT: %OUTPUT% >> IO_DATA
echo exit /B 0 >> IO_DATA
echo REM ---------- >> IO_DATA
echo OUTPUT DEFINED FOR "%INPUT%" Successfully ( OUTPUT Defined = "%OUTPUT%" )
goto begin
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this batch script was originally made by someone calling it artificial intelligence batch script which basically you could call it that.

Comment: Remove the first `@echo off` during debugging phase

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch tried and still would not read it.

Comment: Ask the original author of that script.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the original author is unknown.

Comment: anyone that knows batch, i am most likely making a simple error.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch original author unknown.

Comment: I suggested an external datafile and showed a way for doing it for a very similar program [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22748417/2152082)

Answer (score 1):

> and no thats not the issue

yes, it is.

Analyzing the structure of that batchfile, it's designed to add new labels to itself (last code block), which can be called next time.
Adding that labels to another file doesn't make sense, because you can't call them from there.

Instead of writing to `IO_DATA` it should append to itself `"%~dpnx0"`

Comment: Yes, this would solve the problem, and surely the _original_ program was written this way. The OP said: "_a batch script i modified to output to a file the inputs and outputs_"...